# jQuery: hidden elements are considered "visible", why?

Tags: jquery

I've made a working example of what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/uRhuK/

Try to click on one line:

- Aujourd'hui (lundi 5 mars)
- Demain (mardi 6 mars)
- Après demain (mercredi 7 mars)
- Vendredi 8 mars
- Un autre jour

Then try to click on another line: it works great: it hide the previous and shows the new one.

Now try to re-click on the first line: nothing happens! Why?

Because that code is ok = the element is considered visible:

```
if ($(id).is(':visible')) {
    return;
}
```

This would mean that after one slideUp() the element is considered visible.

Any idea how comes?

[edit]

I've changed my code so now it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/uRhuK/2/ but I don't know if it's clean jQuery code or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"visibility" is a property separate from the "slideup" which manipulates height of the element. Something can be 0px but still "visible"

looking at your code, you are not actually ever resetting the visibility :

```
$('.heuresresume').hide();
$('.heuresdetail').hide();
$('ul.jour > li').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = '#heuresresume' + parseInt(this.id.substr(4));
    console.log('-------------------');
    console.log(id);
    console.log($(id));
    console.log('visible :' + $(id).is(':visible')); 
    console.log('hidden :' + $(id).is(':hidden'));
    if ($(id).is(':visible')) {
        console.log('visible');
        return;
    }
    $('.heuresresume :not(' + id + ')').slideUp('slow');
    $(id).slideDown('slow');
});​
```

You don't ever set anything to not be visible. SlideUP does not modify this property in my experience, only element dimensions.

edit: to simplify things, why not assign a class to the element to designate if it is expanded or contracted? That would be the best, least intrusive approach - piggy back it to the "slideup/down" directives imho

Comment: So this would mean "slideDown" make them visible but "slideUp" doesn't hide them at the end of the slide?

Comment: SlideUp and other jquery elements are all extensions of some core functions. A lot of UI share similar behaviors / code. To accomplish a standardized experience for all these extensible objects, the "lowest necessary work" is done. Visibility is set on "open", "in the case it is otherwise not visible when the function wanted to manipulate it"

this is more of a failsafe feature of the UI widgets / lib thing. You can work with the visibility CSS property if you like, but there are easier ways to derive what you are seeking

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems there's a problem with `'.heuresresume :not('+id+')'` that doesnt ignore the element `id`. Any idea how to properly slideDown everything but this one?

Comment: you would need to write exclusion logic and as mentioned above - associate classes and related generic behaviors - then assign or remove classes on elements to achieve the desired look and feel

- -- any more than that, and I'd be writing it for you :)

edit: Or keep track of what the last ID opened was --- classes is a better approach imho

Comment: I've changed my code so now it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/uRhuK/2/ but I don't know if it's clean jQuery code or not.

Comment: it certainly works but it could be written much cleaner - alas! Where would the gardener be without weeds? Beyond the approach being much more complicated than necessary, I would suggest that you abandon the "visibility" property check - this is largely unnecessary and as other's have pointed out : if you want a vanilla attribute check (over a class assignment / removal) - then simply use `display` instead of visible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Please just add a "display" sample and I'll check your answer. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

check for `display:none` instead of `visible`

Comment: this is the "TL:DR" form of the explanation I provided. I should learn to be more concise :)

Answer (score 0):

Showing/hiding with jQuery or jQueryUI will pretty much always modify the display property (display:none, display:block, etc). Visible is a different property entirely, and is used to hide an element but keep its area occupied.

So to check if something is hidden, or if you are going to hide something yourself, you should almost always check the display css property and not visible.

Comment: the ":visible" selector does not check css visibility

Comment: I didn't say it was. Or if it wasn't clear I didn't mean to suggest it was.

Comment: np...the `:visible` selector does work well and basically checks display

Comment: Oooh okay, I see what you're saying now. I was confused about how :visible worked. I usually just use $('#element').css('display') for better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer..... problem is due to hiding of sub UL LI's

```
 $('.heuresdetail').hide();/* hide sub li*/
```

These are staying hidden at times even when parent UL is display:block